# How to solve method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given, when i pass a variable into another method

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, parameter-passing

## I want to pass this chance variable declared in main_game in Hangman_figure

```
def hangman_figure(chance):
    print("hello world")

    if chance==8:

        print("Select another letter")
        print(chance)

    elif chance== 7:
        print("O")
    elif chance==6:
        print("O")
        print('|')
```

## this is the method where my variable is declared

def main_game(self):

```
    spaces=[]
    chance=9
    for space in range(0,self.word_len):
        spaces.append('_ ')
        print(spaces[space],end=" ")


    for x in range(1,10):
        choose =input('Kindly choose a letter that you think this word contains :')
        if choose in self.word_store:
            position=self.word_store.index(choose)
            spaces[position]= choose
            for y in range(0,self.word_len):
                print(spaces[y],end=" ")


            print("Great!! This letter is present in the word, Keep Going")

        else:
            chance=chance-1 
            #I have declared this chance variable which I need to use

            print("Sorry this letter does not exist in the word")

            self.hangman_figure(chance)
```

## How can I pass this chance variable in my hangman_figure method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using a class. That given your method `hangman_figure` needs to have `self` as an argument. Corrected method:

```
def hangman_figure(self, chance):
   print("hello world")
```

Otherwise `self.hangman_figure(chance)` in `main.py` will cause the error because you call the method on a class instance which counts as giving an argument and you also give `chance` as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @just learned It. I have tried this method and it worked fine now. but apparently my' chance' variable was not passed or maybe not checked in the if-else condition, The condition if chance==8 was not checked. Can you please suggest some changes or tell where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code formatting and limited snippets, but from your usage of `self.hangman_figure` it seems like `hangman_figure` is a class method, so you need to add an argument for `self`:

`def hangman_figure(self, chance):`

You're receiving this error because Python implicitly passes an instance of the class itself in the place of the `self` argument, so with your definition of just `def hangman_figure(chance)`, it interprets the `chance` argument to act as the `self` argument (because the `self` argument doesn't actually *have* to be named `self`), so when you pass in another argument with `self.hangman_figure(chance)`, it's raising the error because you are passing two arguments (including the implicit `self`) instead of the one argument you had included in your original function definition

Comment: Thanks for the solution @awarrier99. I have tried this method and it worked fine now.
but apparently my' chance' variable was not passed or maybe not checked in the if-else condition, The condition if chance==8 was not checked. Can please suggest some changes or error I am doing

Comment: @Adi_Sharma no problem. Sure, can you update your post to include the whole class definition in one snippet so I can try it out?